# How to use API Gateway to fire localhost?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to experiment a little, using `nodejs` and `AWS API Gateway`.

```js
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('HOLA');
})
```

And I've fired using postman to `http://localhost:3000/test` and get the response correctly.

Now I'm trying to play around with AWS API Gateway, but seems like it's not allow to fire to localhost? I'm wondering if there's any get around way for me to just play around

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call localhost via api-gateway, since it refers to localhost of that instance of api-gateway and call will never made to your machine.

You can use services like, https://ngrok.com/ to convert your localhost url to an internet url.

This way, https://youareawesome.ngrok.com will get forwarded to your localhost with a tunnel.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your functionality,

what you can do is to generate a ngrok http url out of your localhost and attach that url to http integration in aws, that will solve your purpose. You can also debug but keep in mind default request timeout is 29 sec.

Find how you can make your localhost puublicly avaialable over here

https://betterprogramming.pub/ngrok-make-your-localhost-accessible-to-anyone-333b99e44b07